# How to make user after registration is not logged in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Today AspNet MVC causes the newly registered user to be logged in.

I need Asp.Net MVC to make the user after registering not logged in.

What class do I get the answer so that the user is not logged in after registering?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // Code below is responsible for entering access level to the new registered user

                if (Session["Anunciante"] != null)
                {
                    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    var role = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Anunciante").SingleOrDefault();

                    if (!UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, role.Name))
                    {
                        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, role.Name);

                        await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);

                        await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user.Id);
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Empresas");
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Se chegamos até aqui e houver alguma falha, exiba novamente o formulário
        return View(model);
  }
```

Comment: Share your ASP.NET Identity Registration POST Method code.

Comment: I updated posting, so you can check how the system gives user level

Comment: I have answered! Please check it and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: My friend is having problems, when user registers and receives a user level not able to access view that has permission for him to access .... but the user accesses after shifting and logging again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **remove** following code from the `Register(RegisterViewModel model)` method.

`await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);`

Comment: Perfect I removed the specified line and it worked, but after registering the user is not redirected to another screen does not work the redirect return ReturnToAction ("Create", "Companies"); is on the same user registration screen

Comment: @Cyberlacs Okay! First mark it as answer! and tell me to which method you want to redirect after the successful registration.

Comment: I want to return here to this url ReturnToAction ("Create", "Companies");

Comment: Put `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Empresas");` in place of `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

Comment: I am wishing to disconnect for this reason

1 User clicks the Advertiser link to create a Session ["Advertiser"] = "Advertiser"
2 With this Session the AccountController receives the Session and inserts in the user the Advertiser permission

3 After the user receives a level of user Roles Asp.Net does not know that the user received this level and does not allow the user to enter the allowed view

Comment: @Cyberlacs Analyze your business logic properly, try to understand what need to do and then write your code accordingly! This type of abrupt solution would not help you ultimately. Best wishes!